# How to call/access .constant variable (string) in index.html?

Tags: angularjs

There seems to be a fair amount if info about constants in angularjs but nobody shows example of how call it in the html files, specifically index.html.

My app.js has:

```
.constant('myConstant',{
        string:'myString',
        size: 30
    });
```

I suppose I have to have it in a controller (do I have to?). I have it being included in myCtrl as 'myConstant'.

So I've tried various things:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{string}}
</div>

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{myConstant.string}}
</div>

<div ng-app"myApp">
    {{myConstant.string}}
</div>
```

I'm just not sure how to expose this string to index.html.  Shouldn't it be a global variable?  I just want to add a version string to the app.

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p3N6u/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the jsFiddle, your `myConstant` was not in your `$scope`.

In jsFiddle example, the myConstant is available in the controller but not in the view because it's not in the `$scope`. The `$scope` is the glue between your controller and the view. If you do `$scope.myConstant = myConstant;` then it will appear. See [AngularJS Scope Doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'myConstant', function ($scope, $rootScope, myConstant) {
        $scope.test = "testing...";
        $scope.myConstant = myConstant;
        console.log(myConstant);
}]);

angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers'] ).constant('myConstant',{
    string:'myString',
    size: 30
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p3N6u/1/

Comment: I pretty much new this was going to be the answer.  I was hoping that the .constant would do some magic and just make its variables available to the entire app (global) without having to $scope them, but I'm now giving up on the idea that angular can do that.  Thanks.

Comment: `$rootScope` will do that for you. Though, I advise creating custom `services` if you plan to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject '`myconstant`' into `myCtrl`.
Then you can use `$scope.string = myconstant.string;`

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{string}}
</div>
```